# Can not stop js code

Tags: javascript

I've got `div` called `"count"` and now I want to increment its value from 0 to 10. This is how I did:

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    var refreshId = function() {
        $('#count').text(i);
        i++;
        if (i > 10) {
            clearInterval(refreshId);
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(refreshId, 500);
    });
</script>
```

But counter doesn't stop. What's wrong?

Comment: [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) expects an `intervalId`, which `setInterval()` provides as its `return` value, rather than the `function` that was bound to the interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clearInterval()` takes an identifier returned by `setInterval()` function.

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    var refreshId;
    var refreshFunction = function() {
        $('#count').text(i);
        i++;
        if (i > 10) {
            clearInterval(refreshId);
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        refreshId = setInterval(refreshFunction, 500);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's recommended to also offer an explanation with code snippets ("*What did you change? Why? What was wrong with the original?*"). A code dump isn't necessarily easy to understand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Works as expected when you paste in console.

```
    var i = 0;
    var refreshId = function() {
        $('#count').text(i);
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        if (i > 10) {
            clearInterval(a);
        }
    };
    a = setInterval(refreshId, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since startTime() will run 500mls, make a counter to increment to 10 inside of it, then clear the interval.

```
var counter = 0;
var tt=setInterval(function(){startTime()},500);

function startTime()
{
    if(counter == 10) {
        clearInterval(tt);
    } else {
        counter++;
    }

    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = counter;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, I don't know exactly what's going on in this code (aside from what you've written) but purely from observation it looks as though refreshID is being called after i == 10.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a recursive `setTimeout`:

```
var i = 0;
var refreshFunction = function() {
    $('#count').text(i);
    i++;
    if (i <= 10) {
        setTimeout(refreshFunction, 500);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(refreshFunction, 500);
});
```